# Can't display image in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use this component SideMenu for displaying other SideMenuButton components, but the image isn't displayed

SideMenu:

```
<template>
    <div id = "side-menu">
        ciao
        <SideMenuButton imgPath="../assets/lens.png"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import SideMenuButton from './SideMenuButton.vue'

export default {
    name: "SideMenu",
    components:{
        SideMenuButton
    }
}
</script>
```

SideMenuButton:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img v-bind:src="imgPath">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "SideMenuButton",
    props:{
        imgPath: String,
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's your file structure? :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/F2EKuSi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the image as props and use in the child the `require` for the img

SideMenu:

```
<template>
        <div id = "side-menu">
            ciao
            <SideMenuButton image="lens.png"/>
        </div>
    </template>
```

SideMenuButton:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <img :src="require(`@/assets/${image}`)">

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "SideMenuButton",
    props:{
        image: String,
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

U need to use assets resources like this

```
<img src="@/assets/lens.png"/>
```

Comment: If I put it as src img it works, but when I put it as prop on imgPath it doesn't

Comment: Try imgPath="/assets/lens.png"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is, that `vue` uses webpack under the hood to bundle required resources (images aswell) into the `dist/` directory. (simply put)
That happens at **buildtime**.

But the image path is a variable, so it can change at **runtime**. Webpack cannot determine the image anymore.

```
<template>
  <div id="side-menu">
    ciao
    <SideMenuButton imgPath="imgPath"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SideMenuButton from './SideMenuButton.vue'

export default {
  name: 'SideMenu',
  components: {
    SideMenuButton
  },
  computed: {
    imgPath () {
      // webpack will replace the given path to import() with the actual "production" image path
      return import('../assets/lens.png')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It is possible that you have to `import()` ***all*** images once somewhere in your app, so that webpack can include them at build time.

If you want to read any further into this topic:

- [vue guide on relative path imports](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)
- [file-loader (prior to webpack version 5)](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)
- [raw-loader (prior to webpack version 5)](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/)
- [url-loader (prior to webpack version 5)](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/)
- [asset modules (since webpack version 5)](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)